# Tomcat 9 error on WAR deployment tries to read logging configuration from wrong location

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, deployment, war

I have a Spring Boot WAR application deployed into a Tomcat 9 installation in a server.

It worked fine until another tool created a configuration file in the server. After this, every time Tomcat launches it fails to deploy the WAR file. It seems to me it is looking at this file as if it was a logging configuration file and somehow the Spring Boot app looks at this as a logging configuration file.

The Spring Boot app has the default logging config, there is no XML file with custom logging configuration. The only thing I have is in the `.properties` a `logging.file.name` property which never worked in the server, only when running locally. I even tried renaming the config file in the server but the Tomcat logs still show the same error. Tomcat is installed in a completely different folder than the `logging_config.ini` file.

Any idea why Tomcat/Spring Boot would be looking at this config file on launch?

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Logback logging from /myPath/logging_config.ini
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:168)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:132)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:332)
        ... 59 more
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.LogbackException: Unexpected filename extension of file [file:/myPath/logging_config.ini]. Should be .xml
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:66)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.configureByResourceUrl(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:191)
        at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:165)
        ... 63 more
```

I checked the `catalina.sh` file, checked the `logging.properties` file, renamed the `ini` file, looked for the file name through all the Tomcat files and found nothing.

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using? In older releases Tomcat used the `LOGGING_CONFIG` environment variable internally, which is also used by Spring Boot.

Comment: 9.0.83 I saw this parameter in the catalina.sh file, but the file is pretty much standard as installed, just set the jvm_home in there, and I dont understand why the issue only appeared after the .ini file was created and tomcat is trying to read it on launch